# C++ Qt Derived Classes

Tags: c++, qt, oop

I'm trying to learn Qt and C++ and having some trouble understanding the C++ this keywork. I've seen examples where a class is derived from QMainWindow and then within the class member functions, a QMenu is added. One example is the "Simple menu" program described on this page:

http://www.zetcode.com/gui/qt4/menusandtoolbars/

In that example, a quit action is created with

```
QAction *quit = new QAction("&Quit", this);
```

However, imagine I want to also derive a class from QMenu and use that to create my menu.

mymenu.h

```
class MainWindow;   // forward declaration

class MyMenu : QMenuBar
{
public:
    MyMenu(MainWindow *main_window);

};
```

mymenu.cpp

```
#include "mymenu.hpp"

MyMenu::MyMenu(MainWindow *main_window) : QMenuBar()
{
    QAction *quit = new QAction("&Quit", main_window);  // Notice here I replaced
                                                        // 'this' with 'main_window'
    QMenu = *file;
    file = menuBar()->addMenu("&File");
    file->addAction(quit);
    connect(quit, SIGNAL(triggered()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work because QAction expects a QObject as a parent. All that being said, there are a couple things that don't make sense to me:

1. If the class MainWindow inherits from QMainWindow, doesn't that make 'MainWindow' a QObject?
2. What is the difference between passing 'this' to QAction from within the class MainWindow, as opposed to passing 'main_window' which is (as far as I can tell) also a pointer to the instance from within the MyMenu class?

I apologize for such a long winded question, but if any of you have made it to the end with me, I would love any suggestions as to what I am missing here. The end goal here is just to create a derived class of QMenu (MyMenu here) and add it to the QMainWindow derived class (MainWindow here) existing in a separate class. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you include MainWindow.h in mymenu.cpp?

Comment: No. Maybe that's the problem? I'm forward declaring MainWindow in mymenu.h with the hope that I can make the menu class not rely on the MainWindow class. It's my first time forward declaring though so I may very well not be doing it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the class MainWindow inherits from QMainWindow, doesn't that make 'MainWindow' a QObject?

Yes, `MainWindow` *is a* `QMainWindow` which *is a* `QObject` (you can see this by browsing the inheritance tree on the API docs).

You have only *forward declared* `MainWindow`. Since the compiler does not have a definition for the class `MainWindow` it can only do miminal things with a pointer to `MainWindow`. In order for the compiler to "know" that `MainWindow` *is a* `QMainWindow` which *is a* `QObject`, you must provide a class definition for `MainWindow`. You can solve your compiler error with:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
```

No dynamic cast is needed

Also, in Qt land to make something "really" a QObject you should put the Q_OBJECT macro on the object:

```
class MyMenu : QMenuBar
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyMenu(MainWindow *main_window);

};
```

It might save you a few headaches later on if you ever plan to use the object for signal/slots or other Qt stuff.

> What is the difference between passing 'this' to QAction from within the class MainWindow, as opposed to passing 'main_window' which
>   is (as far as I can tell) also a pointer to the instance from within
>   the MyMenu class?

`this` is a pointer to your custom `MyMenu` class which *is also a* `QMenuBar`. `main_window` is a pointer to your custom `MainMenu` class which *is also a* a `QMainMenu`. So, two different objects in memory. The second argument of the `QAction` constructor takes a pointer to a parent widget. The parent widget is responsible for managing the memory of its children. Since it takes a `QObject` its reasonable to pass in either `this` or `main_menu`.

---

Also you should probably pass a parent to the `QMenu` constructor.

```
MyMenu::MyMenu(MainWindow *main_window) : QMenuBar(main_window)
```

This way `MyMenu` is correctly deleted when the `MainWindow` is deleted.

The usual Qt paradigm is:

```
MyMenu::MyMenu(<arg1>, <arg2>, ... QObject * parent) : QMenuBar(parent)
```

But in this case forwarding along `main_window` is good enough.

Comment: Mostly great explanation so thank you. For the second question though, I'm trying to understand why the example on ZetCode can pass 'this' to QAction (no cast required), but why I can't pass 'main_window' without a dynamic cast even though now that I've moved the menu functionality out of the MainWindow class itself. Could you help clarify that?

Comment: Yes. Can you tell me what error message you get when you try to pass `main_window` without a cast? This may just be a part of C++ I don't know about, so seeing the error message might help me figure out what's going on.

Comment: no matching function for call to ‘QAction::QAction(const char [6], MainWindow*&)’ quit = new QAction("&Quit", my_main_window);

Comment: That's a great question and I really want to find out the answer. I'll look into it

Comment: Just curious while I'm getting my Qt build setup... did the dynamic cast fix the problem?

Comment: No it didn't. I'll post error in next comment. I'm putting the code somewhere you can grab it if you wouldn't mind taking a look. Thanks again.

Comment: cannot dynamic_cast ‘((Menus*)this)->Menus::my_main_window’ (of type ‘class MainWindow*’) to type ‘class QObject*’ (source is a pointer to incomplete type)
  quit = new QAction("&Quit", dynamic_cast<QObject*>(my_main_window));

Comment: You can find the full project here: http://www.naturaldesignwebsites.com/QScope.tar.gz
It doesn't do much but fail to make a menu right now so it's hopefully not too unruly ;)

Comment: The dynamic cast you suggested would be in /src/controllers/menus.cpp if you do look at what I'm doing.

Comment: The `MainWindow*&` doesn't imply that `MainWindow` is incomplete, just that the argument used is an lvalue of type `MainWindow*`.  (Of course, here we expect the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to apply immediately after the compiler figures out the correct function overload.)